# Backbone and jQuery trigger / bind custom event not heard

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm writing a backbone app within an ASP.NET MVC page, and I'm having a truly baffling (to me) problem with using two custom events.

So, the MVC View (Planning.cshtml) has a select control which triggers the Backbone router to fetch a model on change. This model takes a good 10 seconds or so to load, so I want to disable the select while it loads to prevent multiple requests. To do this, I'm having my router trigger two custom events: `'subview-loading'` and `'subview-loading-complete'`, and having my MVC view listen for these events.

The problem I'm having is that the router can hear both events, but Planning.cshtml will only hear the `'subview-loading-complete'` event, not the first event.

Planning.cshtml code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var router = new Router({
    el: '#TermPlanningReport'
  });

  var $routerEl = $(router.el);

  $routerEl.bind('subview-loading', function() {
    console.log('Planning.cshtml heard subview-loading');
    //disable control
  });
  $routerEl.bind('subview-loading-complete', function() {
    console.log('Planning.cshtml heard subview-loading-complete');
    //enable control 
  });

});
```

Router.viewTerm() - the route method loading the model:

```
viewTerm: function (term) {
    
    var that = this,
        termModel = new PlanningTerm({ term: term }),
        $thisEl = $(that.el);

    //for testing purposes, see if router can hear itself...
    $thisEl.on('subview-loading', function() {
      console.log('router heard subview-loading'); 
    });
    $thisEl.on('subview-loading-complete', function () {
      console.log('router heard subview-loading-complete');
    }); 

    //trigger loading
    $thisEl.trigger('subview-loading');  

    // fetch data for model
    termModel.fetch({
      success: function (model, response, options) {
        $thisEl.trigger('subview-loading-complete'); 
        //render a vew...
      },
      error: function (model, response, options) {
        $thisEl.trigger('subview-loading-complete');
        //render a view...
      }
    });
},
```

Finally, my console output:

```
router heard subview-loading
router heard subview-loading-complete
Planning.cshtml heard subview-loading-complete
```

The variables `$routerEl` and `$thisEl` are both returning the same element properly.

Comment: Where is `viewTerm()` called? Maybe the `subview-loading` trigger is called before it is listened to by `Planning.cshtml`?

Comment: It's a registered route within the router.routes object.

Comment: Can you show code at jsbin?